# Can i use removeEventListener in this way?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am trying to toggle event listener on child elements, can I use removeEventListener like in this code:

```
    function changeColor(){
        container.addEventListener('click',function color(){
            if(activatePen==true){
                let slab=document.querySelectorAll('div .item');
                slab.forEach((slabs)=>{
                    slabs.addEventListener('mouseover', function changeGridColor(){
                        slabs.setAttribute('style','background: blue; font-size:30px; text-align: center; border:0px solid white');
                    });
                });
            }
            else{
                let slab=document.querySelectorAll('div .item');
                slab.forEach((slabs)=>{
                    slabs.removeEventListener('mouseover', function changeGridColor(){
                        slabs.setAttribute('style','background: white; font-size:30px; text-align: center; border:0px solid white');
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: no, it needs to be the same function, period. Not just defined the same, it needs to be literally the same thing.

Comment: in my opinion, this is one of the huge strengths of jQuery -- jQuery tracks all event listeners you attach to a DOM element internally, so you could do something like `$slabs.off('mouseover')` to just unassign anything that might have been assigned to mouseover

Comment: Are you sure you need to add and remove the event listener? Why not just have the event listener check whether `activePen` is true?

Comment: @Barmar It still changed the color, I think it is because I was not removing that listener that it keeps on listening to the event once it has started

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but I wonder if you'd be better off adding a "highlightOnHover" class to your containing div when it's clicked, and then having a .highlightOnHover .item:hover css style to handle the slabs, if all you are doing is applying CSS to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a named function in order to remove it. Event listener functions receive an `Event` object as the parameter, you can get the target element from that.

```js
function changeGridColor(e) {
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute('style', 'background: blue; font-size:30px; text-align: center; border:0px solid white');
}

var activatePen = false;

document.querySelector("#activate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  activatePen = !activatePen;
  changeColor();
});

function changeColor() {
  let slab = document.querySelectorAll('div .item');
  if (activatePen) {
    slab.forEach((slabs) =>
      slabs.addEventListener('mouseover', changeGridColor));
  } else {
    slab.forEach((slabs) =>
      slabs.removeEventListener('mouseover', changeGridColor));
  }
}

changeColor();
```

```html
<div id="container" <div id>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>

<button id="activate">Toggle hover</button>
```

Comment: this has worked for me but than I have a doubt, in your solution instead of using targeted event to set attribute i used slabs(used for each child element in for loop) which I tried to pass as a parameter while calling function from eventListener but what it did was it even changed the color of all other child elements, so I did something wrong with it or this only works while getting parameter from target event?

Comment: I've added HTML so you can run the snippet. It only changes the color of the element you mouse over. But you don't have a `mouseout` so the color never changes back.

Comment: It actually looks like you want two event listeners, one that makes it blue, another that makes it white, and you want to alternate between them.

Answer (score 1):

No. You have 2 declaration of some function - it allocates 2 different references. You can:

**Create function once and call it by a name**

```js
const changeGridColor=(e)=>{
  // e.currentTarget.setAttribute()
}
slabs.addEventListener('mouseover',changeGridColor);
slabs.removeEventListener('mouseover',changeGridColor);
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the function needs to bound to a specific `slabs` binding.

Comment: It shouldn't be problem as long as we're iterating over the same list of elements.

Comment: When I create function outside the eventListener and than when I call it within the evntListener than instead of changing the color of a single targeted child element it changes color of all child elements

Comment: How will it know which element to call `slabs.setAttribute()` on ?

Comment: @Barmar I misunderstoon your point. Yeah you are right. I was just pointing out the references on listeners.